# Coffeescript weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am trying to decide if want to use Coffeescript or avoid it :)

This is one weird behaviour I had just with this simple function:

```
equals = (lhs, rhs) -> lhs == rhs ? "IT IS TRUE" : "IT IS FALSE"
alert(equals(1, 2))
```

This function returns false, not "IT IS FALSE" as expected

Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: don't think it is a duplicate, now I can see that the issue is in the ternary operator, not before.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure CoffeeScript supports the ternary operator like that, try this instead:

```
equals = (lhs, rhs) -> if lhs == rhs then "IT IS TRUE" else "IT IS FALSE"
```